# UnicodeDecodeError on sqlalchemy connection.execute() for select queries

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-unicode

I'm using sqlalchemy core to execute string based queries. I have set charset to `utf8mb4` on the connection string like  this:

`"mysql+mysqldb://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}?charset=utf8mb4"`

For some simple select queries (e.g, `select name from users where id=XXX limit 1`), when the resultset has some unicode characters (e.g, `'`, `ì`, etc), it errors out with the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 11: invalid start byte`

But the error itself is not reproducible. When I run the same query from a python shell, it works without errors. But it errors out on a web request or background job.

I'm using Python 3.8 and sqlalchemy 1.3.24.

I have also tried explicitly specifying `charset: utf8mb4` as a `connect_args` property with `create_engine()`.

The underlying database is mysql 5.7 and all the unicode columns have `utf8mb4` explicitly set as the characters set in the schema.
Update: The database is actually AWS RDS Aurora MySQL.

Appreciate any insights on the error or how to reproduce it reliably.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL documentation [Connect-Time Error Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html#charset-connection-error-handling-connect-time) describes a bug in the MySQL 8.0 client library when you use the MySQL 8.0 client library to connect to a MySQL 5.7 server with the utf8mb4 charset. The MySQL 8.0 client asks for the utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci collation, but the MySQL 5.7 server does not recognize that collation, so the server silently falls back to the latin1 charset with latin1_swedish_ci collation. Subsequently the server sends latin1 result sets, but the client thinks that it is receiving utf8mb4, which eventually results in a `UnicodeDecodeError`. As a workaround you have to explicitly `SET NAMES utf8mb4`. I created an issue [mysqlclient#504](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/504) to ask that the python client do that every time.

To confirm that the charset is incorrect after connecting, double check the server’s value of [`character_set_client`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client) (the charset that statements are interpreted in), [`character_set_connection`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection) (the charset that statements are converted to), and [`character_set_results`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_results) (the charset that result sets are sent as). If they are `latin1` despite you trying to connect using utf8mb4, then this bug may have been triggered.

```py
with con.cursor() as c:
  c.execute("show variables like 'character_set_%'")
  for row in c:
    print(row)
(b'character_set_client', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_connection', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_database', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_filesystem', b'binary')
(b'character_set_results', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_server', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_system', b'utf8')
(b'character_sets_dir', b'/usr/share/mysql/charsets/')
```

I believe that a workaround of the issue would be to do the following after connecting:

```py
# explicitly set connection charset to the same as MySQLdb.connect()
con.query("SET NAMES utf8mb4")
con.store_result()
```

Comment: For my case, only the `character_set_database` and `character_set_server` are set to `latin1`, the rest are correctly set as `utf8mb4`. Would you still say that this is the root cause?

Comment: @ModasserBillah, `character_set_server` configures the default [character set used for `CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html) among other things, so it’s highly recommended to set it to `utf8mb4` to prevent other errors. But I don’t think that it would cause a client-side UnicodeDecodeError.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with `use_unicode=true` parameter in the url?